# TCP connection long delay at Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, troubleshooting

I have strange problem at my Windows 7 laptop. All TCP connections have some delay between TCP handshake and actually sending data. This makes all browsers (tried Aurora, Chrome, Opera and IE 9) hang for some time. Also this causes Skype to come online for very long time (up to 5 minutes).

I checked network traffic with Network Monitor. I have found out there is a random (4 to 30 seconds) delay between TCP handshake and sending data:

```
-------------- handshake begin ---------------------
3   1.1434242   CAVE    serverfault.com TCP TCP:Flags=......S.
5   1.1630603   serverfault.com CAVE    TCP TCP:Flags=...A..S.
7   1.1635530   CAVE    serverfault.com TCP TCP:Flags=...A....
-------------- handshake end --------------------------
215 14.1408929  CAVE    serverfault.com HTTP    HTTP:Request
```

Also I've noticed when I started Fiddler (so any browser traffic went through it) this delay has disappeared. I have no explanation of this.

I have Symantec Client Security installed. However even when I stopped it completely (disabled all related services and rebooted) problem was same

Comment: Are you using any kind of proxy? Also are you on your home network you administer or is this a network that someone else is the administrator (i.e. The network at work or free public wifi)?

Comment: Do other PC's in your home have the same problem? Do you use wifi or a cable?

Comment: I experience that in both home and work network. Problem occurs only at my PC. Any other PCs in both networks have no such problem. Problem occurs on both wifi and cable connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the reason of the problem. I use Open Text Socks client. When it's enabled problem occurs. When it's disabled everything works fine. I tried another socks proxy client (Proxifier) - it doesn't cause such problem.